# How to serve vueJS cli app in flask server

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, deployment

How can I server vue.js application using flask restfull plus. I was using regular flask before and index.html file, but i update code to use flask restfull plus, and vue cli app, but i am not sure how to deploy like html. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can still use flask to render index.html on `/` route

Comment: do you know any example i can look up? I decide to separate them into separate dockers containers

Comment: If you want to have seperate docker container then I would recomend using nginx container to serve static app and special `api` endpoint rule for api.